# Convert column[Time] to Timestamp mysql

Tags: mysql

Seeing the question you might find it as duplicate. But I have researched and its not.

The problem is I have a column in my table with "TIME" data-type. Now I want to convert the column to "TIMESTAMP".

I have tried using **Modify** too.
The query

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`temp_table` MODIFY COLUMN `time` TIMESTAMP
```

But this doesn't work. The Error I got

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '20:00:00' for column 'time' at row 1
```

Alter table change column too doesn't work. Is there any way which I can convert the column TIMESTAMP.

The last option that I can see is convert the column to VARCHAR then update appending a date and then convert to timestamp.

UPDATE:

Tried coverting Time to DATETIME. Which gave no error but the data is not correct. After changing the column the time "20:00:00" changed to "2020-00-00 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add another "TIMESTAMP" column to your table and transfer data from you "TIME" column to new "TIMESTAMP" column. Then you could drop original "TIME" column and rename new column to "TIME".

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`temp_table` ADD COLUMN `time_stamp` TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE table SET time_stamp = TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(), `time`);
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`temp_table` 
         DROP COLUMN `time`;         
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`temp_table` 
         CHANGE COLUMN `time_stamp` `time` TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to convert the column, but yes, this worked fine. Just have to disable 'Safe update' in workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table test(`time` time);
insert into test values('10:00:00'), ('20:00:00');
alter table test add ts timestamp null;
update test set ts=`time`;
alter table test drop `time`;
alter table test change ts `time` timestamp not null;
```

Comment: it worked perfetcly fine for me. What were you expecting for results?

Comment: For me it gave error. Incorrect datetime value: '20:00:00' for column 'time' at row 1. I am expecting the result to be some date maybe 1970-01-01 20:00:00. Something Like that